# DWT Java Script Library Progress Dialogue Automatically Displays with Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am incorporating the Dynamic Web Twain javascript library into my angular application to allow my end users to scan using a web browser instead of a desktop application.

Upon loading the page, the progress bar immediately pops up. This is not expected behavior, nor does it happen when I use angular 4. I am using angular 5 at work. It also makes no difference which browser I use (IE, Chrome, Firefox).

The version of my Angular is:

```
> Angular CLI: 1.6.6 Node: 9.4.0 OS: win32 x64 Angular: 5.2.3 ...
> animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms ... http,
> language-service, platform-browser ... platform-browser-dynamic,
> router
> 
> @angular/cli: 1.6.6 @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
> @angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29 @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
> @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0 @ngtools/webpack: 1.9.6
> @schematics/angular: 0.1.17 typescript: 2.5.3 webpack: 3.10.0
```

I have included the javascript library into my newly created Angular project using these commands:

```
npm install dwt --save
npm install @type/dwt --save
```

Also note that my webtwain.min.js is added to the scripts within my angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/dwt/dist/dynamsoft.webtwain.min.js"
```

Here is the layout of my project:

[image]

Finally, here is my component.ts file and its related html (it doesn't matter how I populate the html, the result is the same):

```
    /// <reference types="dwt" />

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scan',
  template: '<button (click)="acquireImage()">Scan Document</button><div id="dwtcontrolContainer"></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./scan.component.css']
})
export class ScanComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  acquireImage(): void {
    const dwObject = Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.GetWebTwain('dwtcontrolContainer');
    dwObject.IfShowIndicator = false;
    const bSelected = dwObject.SelectSource();
    if (bSelected) {
      const onAcquireImageSuccess = () => { dwObject.CloseSource(); };
      const onAcquireImageFailure = onAcquireImageSuccess;
      dwObject.OpenSource();
      dwObject.AcquireImage({}, onAcquireImageSuccess, onAcquireImageFailure);
    }
  }

}
```

Finally here is the result:
[image]

The 'progressbar' shown with a value of 0% pops up immediately. In angular 4, this does not happen. Any thoughts on what is causing this? I am trying to read up on the changes between 4 and 5, specifically asynchronous and synchronous loading but I am still new to this framework.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Tom from Dynamsoft.

What you posted here is a known issue in v13.3 of the SDK Dynamic Web TWAIN.

Here is the fix

1. Update CSS (dynamsoft_dwt_html5.css) to add the following

   `dialog[closed] {
       display: none;
   }`
2. Update dynamsoft.webtwain.initiate.js to apply the new CSS rule

   `m.showDialog=function(y){var z=this,v;if(z.open){j.error("showDialog called on open dialog.");return}z.open=i;`**`z.removeAttribute("closed");`**

   `m.closeDialog=function(t){var v=this;if(!v.open){j.error("closeDialog called on closed dialog.")}v.open=o;v.removeAttribute("open");`**`v.setAttribute("closed","closed");`**

   `y.push('<dialog class="dynamsoft-dwt-dialogProgress"` **`closed="closed"`** `style="top:30%">`

Since the code is minimized, it might look different in your own copy of the JS, if you like, you can email our support team (support@dynamsoft.com, if possible, please use your business email address) for the patch. Thanks.

BTW, the patch will be part of **v13.4** soon to be released.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will try these steps and report back (or I may email you as I do have the minimized version of your files).

Comment: The fix you provided worked. Looking forward to the official 13.4 release. Thanks!

Comment: sir, currently im doing the same but im facing this error `Failed to load http://www.dynamsoft.com/library/dwt/Resources/WinDWT_Trial_13.3.0.0115.zip?t=603985610: Redirect from 'http://www.dynamsoft.com/library/dwt/Resources/WinDWT_Trial_13.3.0.0115.zip?t=603985610' to 'https://www.dynamsoft.com/library/dwt/Resources/WinDWT_Trial_13.3.0.0115.zip?t=603985610' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth In your case, it's a good idea to use the /Resources/ locally. The steps are
1. Copy /Resources/ to **src\assets**
2. Add   **"assets/Resources"** to **"assets"** in .angular-cli.json
3. Update the following line in dynamsoft.webtwain.initiate.min.js
`Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.ResourcesPath="http://www.dynamsoft.com/library/dwt/Resources";` to `Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.ResourcesPath="assets/Resources";`

Comment: @Tom.K can you please take a look at this question aswell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022507/angular-4-dwt-javascript-library-not-working-in-model

Comment: Sure, will post the reply there