# Angular 4 DWT JavaScript Library not working in model

Tags: javascript, angular, scanning

Currently, I want use DWT Javascript library to scan the documents I followed these steps 
http://www.codepool.biz/javascript-global-library-angular-cli.html
for a new project, it worked perfectly fine. When I try to incorporate into my main project I'm facing few issues like the `progress bar model is will be present all the time no matter what happens`.

[image]

but when using the same code inside the model, not able to get the result.

**code**

```
<ng-template #scanModal let-c="close " let-d="dismiss ">
   <div class="modal-header ">
      <h6 class="modal-title text-uppercase ">Scan Document</h6>
      <button type="button " class="close pointer" aria-label="Close " (click)="d( 'Cross click') ">
      <span aria-hidden="true ">&times;</span>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <button (click)="acquireImage()">Scan Document</button>
      <div id="dwtcontrolContainer"></div>
   </div>
   <span id="alert alert-danger">&nbsp; </span>
   <div id="info" style="display:none; padding:20px 30px; width: 350px; border: solid 1px #e7e7e7;">
      The <strong>PDF Rasterizer</strong> is not installed on this PC
      <br />Please click the button below to get it installed
      <p> <button (click)="downloadPDFR();">Install PDF Rasterizer</button></p>
      <i><strong>The installation is a one-time process</strong> <br />
      It might take some time depending on your network.</i>
   </div>
   <br/>
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

when the model opens I'm getting this error

> RegisterComponent.html:376 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'SelectSource' of null

there is no change in the TS code i just pasted HTML snippet into the model.

**TS code**

```
acquireImage(): void {
    const dwObject = Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.GetWebTwain('dwtcontrolContainer');
    const bSelected = dwObject.SelectSource();
    if (bSelected) {
      const onAcquireImageSuccess = () => { dwObject.CloseSource(); };
      const onAcquireImageFailure = onAcquireImageSuccess;
      dwObject.OpenSource();
      dwObject.AcquireImage({}, onAcquireImageSuccess, onAcquireImageFailure);
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, please check out the other post
[dwt-java-script-library-progress-dialogue-automatically-displays-with-angular-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669929/dwt-java-script-library-progress-dialogue-automatically-displays-with-angular-5)

For the 2nd problem. If would appear to be caused by missing of Types definition. Have you included the following line in your TS?

`/// <reference types="dwt" />`

Comment: I have followed both method still getting same issue

Comment: Can you email Dynamsoft Support and send over your code?